# Silverlight + RIA Services: How to return from one invoke operation before another invoke operation completes?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am having trouble polling to get the status of a long running invoke operation in my domain service.  Specifically, all calls to the invoke operation function used to poll for the status are not returning until after the long running invoke operation finishes.

Here are the details:

1. I am using Silverlight 5 with RIA Services.
2. On my server side domain service class (example code below), I have a long running operation in an invoke operation named RunLongOperation.
3. I also have a second invoke operation function named CheckStatusOfLongOperation that retrieves the status of the long running operation.
4. In my Silverlight client, I call RunLongOperation.  After that, every 5 seconds, I call CheckStatusOfLongOperation.
5. According to Fiddler, every 5 seconds, CheckStatusOfLongOperation is being called.  However, there is no response for any of the calls until RunLongOperation is complete.

What can I do to get CheckStatusOfLongOperation to return sooner?

ASP.NET Server code:

```
Public Class MyDomainService
    Inherits DomainService

    <Invoke()>
    Public Function RunLongOperation() As String

        'Long running operation, some database queries,
        'but mostly in-memory operations

    End Function

    <Invoke()>
    Public Function CheckStatusOfLongOperation() As String

        'Checks a single variable and return status

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: What do your calls to `RunLongOperation` and `CheckStatusOfLongOperation` look like?

Comment: I modified my example code with some more details.

Comment: It's the client code I'm interested in seeing. It might be the answer that you have to do the long running operation in a separate thread on the server.

Comment: I added the client code to the example.  I removed some extraneous details, but all the essentials are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably seeing locking on the session state. Check here for instructions on how to turn off locking: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2010/09/27/asp-net-compatible-wcf-services-concurrency-problem.aspx

Comment: That sounds like my problem. I took a look at my use of session state and all but a handful of variables need to be kept there. The rest can be moved to something like MemoryCache (I'll use a key to make sure values stay unique to the user).  Of the variables I'd like to continue storing in the session, I can isolate the reads and writes into separate DomainServices/classes/functions/blocks of code (take your pick, whatever gets the job done or is simplest).  How would I go about marking one as read/write and the other as read-only?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again. Between the link you provided and some additional research, I was able to isolate these two functions as read only. For the benefit of others, adding this code to Global.asax.vb will mark the two functions as read-only and allow them to be executed asynchronously and simultaneously: Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) // If Context.Request.Path.EndsWith("RunLongOperation") OrElse Context.Request.Path.EndsWith("CheckStatusOfLongOperation") Then // HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly) // End If // End Sub